# Unable to insert data in mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql

Here is a little php program I did a few years ago (it worked then...)
As I recently tried to incorporate it to my new "website", no data is inserted in my table...

(when I run it, I don't receive any error message)

If anyone could tell me what's wrong, I'd be very glad. THX!

---

```
// data,from a form on another page, that I want to insert in my db

$nom = $_POST['nom'];  
$prenom = $_POST['prenom'];  
$date = $_POST['date'];  
$identifiant = $_POST['identifiant'];  
$password = $_POST['password'];


// connexion to my database  
$connexion = mysql_connect("mysql5.000webh.com","a888888_user","mypassword");
mysql_select_db("a888888_mydatabase",$connexion);

// creation and sending of SQL query  
$requete = "insert into panel values   
('','$nom','$prenom','$date','$identifiant','$password')";
mysql_query($requete);

echo "Vos donnees ont ete envoyees !";  
include('page.html');

// closing Mysql connexion
mysql_close();
```

---

Comment: For a quick debug make the `mysql_query($requete)` line say: `mysql_query($requete) or die(mysql_error());` to give us some kind of error message.

Comment: I hope you're aware that this code is vulnerable to SQL injection - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @MarcusRecck: TYVM! i did what you said and figured it out!

the error message was "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"
I added one more value, checked, it worked!

thanks again for your quick answer, have a nice day!

Comment: @therefromhere: i am now!... but what shall I do to my code to avoid it?

Comment: @ericl read the link I posted ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly executing your query like,

```
mysql_query($requete);
```

Use a variable to fetch the result of the query using a variable like,

```
$result = mysql_query($requete);
```

Now use a simple check whether your query was executed or not by just using an if statement and then use the `mysql_error()` function to see the error.

```
if ( !$result ) {
    die( mysql_error() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the fields in which to inser the values:

```
$requete = "insert into panel values   
('','$nom','$prenom','$date','$identifiant','$password')"
```

Comment: That makes no sense, if the number of fields specified here equals to the number of fields in the database. They should match in number, order and type.

Comment: Hi!
actually, my db_table had one more field, named access with a default value of 0, after password.
I just thought I could omit in the line you quote because no value  was inserted.